# (React Native) onPress doesn't work for Text component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text, react-props, onpress

I'm trying to get the onPress to work, but "hi" is not being printed. In fact, the gray default background that should show behind the text when it is clicked does not show. If I replace the nested text with a TouchableHighlight component, it does print. However, this needs to be a continuous flow of text that wraps onto the next line, so TouchableHighlight will not be suitable.

```
<Text>   
    <Text>Thanks for visiting the app! Please click </Text>
    <Text onPress={() => { console.log("hi") }}> here right now! </Text>
    <Text>to sign in</Text>
</Text>
```

The actual code is slightly more complex than the above, but it's basically a few text components nested inside one larger text component (this is so the text can wrap to next line and looks like one piece of text). Any ideas on how to get onPress for the text component to work? Thanks!

What it should look like (bold text represents what's clickable):

Please click **here

right now** to sign in.

What it should NOT look like (cannot use View as outside holder instead of text):

```
Please click here right to sign in. 
             now
```

Comment: Turns out my solution was to just clean and rebuild the project....

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and i used a combination of `Text` and  `TouchableOpacity` wrapper in a View with `flexWrap : wrap`, 
check out a [demo](https://snack.expo.io/0fnTEHRMB)

here is the code :

```js
const test = () => {
  return ( 
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.textPart1}>
      test you text {' '}
      </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.textPart2}>
       clickable text
        </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>    
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'row',
    flexWrap:'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
    padding: 10,
  },
  textPart1: {
    fontFamily: 'Raleway-Regular',
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#5F5F5F',
  },
  textPart2: {
    fontFamily: 'Raleway-Regular',
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#428947',
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
  },
});
```

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but actually the issue is still there. Yes, I can tap the text, but the outside view doesn't wrap all the text correctly (it's still laying out the text components in a row like they are views)

Comment: sorry your example doesn't work. I'll update my question to say what that looks like

Comment: no problem, i tested with onPress in Text it does show log https://snack.expo.io/ZVd_tOOgyR

Comment: yeah but that's not working on my end and I'm not too sure why

Comment: sorry to bother but even your code is working https://snack.expo.io/e0BzEvCUM

Comment: hmm yeah but it's not on my end for some reason. the code is similar, not exactly the same, but the structure is the same

Answer (score 0):

```
<Text 
style={{ color: "darkgrey" }}>
Dont have an account ?
</Text>

<Text 
style={{ color: "blue", textDecorationLine:'underline' }} 
onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Register")}> 
Sign up </Text>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck